# Delete the memory of a Double data type variable

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm trying to use Garbage collector, GC.collect(), to delete the memory of my variables after a certain period of time that my program runs. It worked well and did what I needed for my integer variables, however when I attempted this for my Double variables or Long it ran an error, stating that GC.collect is integer based.

My question is, is there an alternative service method that I can use to clear the memory of my variables that are of type double or Long?

Thanks

Comment: In addition to @CihanYakar's answer (you don't understand how the GC works), you should really read up on _Value Types_ and _Reference Types_.  A `double` is a value type, it isn't GC-ed (unless it's a member of an instance of a reference type).  But as noted in the answer, you generally don't need to think about the GC.  Another thing (that you didn't mention) that you should understand is the `IDisposable` pattern and realize that, although it does have to do with _cleaning up_, it isn't really tied to the GC and it is something you should be worrying about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might also mention that the garbage collector only cares about objects, i.e. classes. Value types, i.e. int, double, structs, etc are either part of a object, and thus tracked and collected as part of that object. Or part of the stack, and thus released automatically when the method they are used in returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an int variable to GC.Collect(n), but it means "collect nth generation," not "remove n."

You misunderstand entirely how garbage collectors work. GC is an automated process, and you don't need to remove references from memory explicitly. To eliminate memory leaks, you should not leave unnecessary references and dispose of all the disposable objects when they are no longer needed.